# Can I retrieve an associated type of the implemenattion of a trait?

Tags: rust, type-traits, associated-types

Given the following trait:

```rs
trait Trait { type Associated; }
```

and an impelmentation:

```rs
struct Struct {}
impl Trait for Struct { type Associated = u32; }
```

I would like to retrieve the associated type `Associated` of `Struct`.
Somehting like (`Struct as Trait` is invalid rust):

```rs
struct AnotherStruct {
   prop: (Struct as Trait)::Associated
}
```

Is there any way to retrieve the asscoiated type?

Note that I am aware that I can impelment a function like:

```rs
fn f<T: Trait>(arg: T::Associated) -> T::Associated { arg }
```

However, I would like to get the associaetd type to set the type of a struct property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were so close. The correct fully qualified syntax is `<Type as Trait>::AssociatedType`. You can read more about it in [The Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#fully-qualified-syntax-for-disambiguation-calling-methods-with-the-same-name).

Your example should look like this.

```rust
trait Trait {
    type Associated;
}

struct Struct {}

impl Trait for Struct {
    type Associated = u32;
}

struct AnotherStruct {
   prop: <Struct as Trait>::Associated
}
```